# linux slowed down after running cat on a large file on ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, zsh

I ran cat on a huge file (over 8 million lines) by accident, and tried to terminate with ctrl-c, ctrl-\, and it didn't stop:

```bsh
cat hugefile.csv
```

I closed the terminal window hoping that the process would terminate. However it's slowed down almost to a halt. Ssh is slow and the already running servers (api's, web apps etc) all slowed down almost to a halt.

I looked for dangling terminal sessions and killed all of them. I also looked for processes that are hogging the cpu / the network / the disk, but nothing seems to be using any significant amount of resources.

Why could this be happening?

ps: The remote machine is ubuntu 16.04, and I was using a zsh shell on the remote.

This is the current `ps aux | grep sshd` output:

```bsh
root      1267  0.0  0.0  65508  3356 ?        Ss   Jan14   0:03 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root     16447  0.0  0.0  92796  6924 ?        Ss   02:35   0:00 sshd: muhsin [priv]
muhsin   16482  0.0  0.0  92796  3276 ?        S    02:35   0:00 sshd: muhsin@pts/0
muhsin   16596  0.0  0.0  12940   932 pts/0    S+   02:37   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox sshd
```

And this is what I see on `glances` (to see cpu / network / disk usage):

```bsh
ubuntu (Ubuntu 16.04 64bit / Linux 4.4.0-1119-aws)               Uptime: 6 days, 10:58:21

CPU       1.3%  nice:     0.0%   LOAD    4-core   MEM     78.8%  active:    12.6G   SWAP      0.0%
user:     0.6%  irq:      0.0%   1 min:    0.07   total:  15.7G  inactive:  1.13G   total:       0
system:   0.6%  iowait:   0.0%   5 min:    0.04   used:   12.3G  buffers:   1011M   used:        0
idle:    98.7%  steal:    0.0%   15 min:   0.05   free:   3.32G  cached:    1.69G   free:        0

NETWORK     Rx/s   Tx/s   TASKS 210 (611 thr), 1 run, 209 slp, 0 oth sorted automatically
_24a61ca3    1Kb   448b
_9e7afe3a     0b     0b     CPU%  MEM%   PID USER        NI S Command
_eb2f1d84     0b     0b      0.0  24.7 13039 root         0 S python main.py
_47feb354     0b     0b      0.0  24.7  3382 root         0 S python main.py
_7b011cd5     0b     0b      0.3   4.3 24092 root         0 S python main.py
docker0       0b     0b      1.3   4.1 24365 root         0 S python /opt/miniconda3/envs/env/bin/g
ens3        648b    2Kb      1.0   3.9 29923 root         0 S python /opt/miniconda3/envs/env/bin/g
lo          512b   512b      0.3   2.4 12557 root         0 S python -u listener.py
_h13405f3     0b     0b      0.0   2.2  3013 root         0 S python -u listener.py
_h21602b0     0b     0b
_h2f55e7c     0b     0b
_h3a8e27e     0b     0b   Warning or critical alerts (one entry)
2021-01-21 02:40:04       2021-01-21 02:39:08 (ongoing) - MEM (78.8)
```

And this is the htop output:

```bsh
  1  [                                   0.0%]   Tasks: 99, 401 thr; 1 running
  2  [||                                 4.3%]   Load average: 0.05 0.04 0.05
  3  [                                   0.0%]   Uptime: 6 days, 11:00:01
  4  [|                                  0.5%]
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||11.3G/15.7G]
  Swp[                                  0K/0K]

  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
16710 muhsin     20   0 24892  3728  2932 R  1.0  0.0  0:00.11 htop
    1 root       20   0 38080  5592  3488 S  0.0  0.0  0:08.40 /sbin/init
  411 root       20   0 35268  6716  6392 S  0.0  0.0  0:08.20 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
  441 root       20   0 94768   960   784 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /sbin/lvmetad -f
  473 root       20   0 42836  3492  2464 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.72 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
  752 systemd-t  20   0   97M  2004  1800 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
  728 systemd-t  20   0   97M  2004  1800 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.44 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
 1043 root       20   0 16120  2616  1768 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.22 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclie
 1179 root       20   0  5216   116     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:08.32 /sbin/iscsid
 1180 root       10 -10  5716  3516  2432 S  0.0  0.0  0:38.91 /sbin/iscsid
 1184 root       20   0  4392  1272  1184 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/acpid
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4FilterF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit
```

Comment: When you say slowed to a halt, what exactly do you mean?  Do you mean ssh response or the system as a whole?  The data you posted shows 98% idle so it doesn't look like the system is burdened.  Try killing sshd outright...  pkill sshd... systemd should restart it automatically.  Maybe it's hung in some weird way that's bogging down memory or network.

Comment: Don't use `cat` to look at text files - it is bad practice. If for example you accidentally `cat` a binary file, you will mess up your terminal. Use `less` instead.

Comment: @mikem (sorry for late answer) The system as a whole. I don't want to reproduce this as it's a production server. I'll respond once I have access to a different server and have reproduced the problem. I just had something similar though. I tried to read an insane amount of sql results using python and everything froze until that process finished. I don't understand how one process can hog the resources (which I don't even know if it's the cpu or network or whatever) completely and freely so easily